# Custom sequence for Swift Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, generator, sequence, ios8

I have a container class that has an underlying dictionary. I have implemented subscripts for this class to access member of the underlying dictionary. Now, I am trying to create a sequence on this class so that I could iterate over all the elements of the underlying dictionary by using 'for-in' loop on the class instance itself. I have been looking to find some examples for Sequences for Swift Dictionary but could not find anything that explains the stuff well. I have seen some custom sequence examples for Swift Array but none for the Swift Dictionary. I would really appreciate if anyone could explain how I can achieve that. Following is the code for the class (no sequence code yet as I am not sure where to begin)

```
import Foundation

class STCQuestionList : GeneratorType, SequenceType {

private var questionDict: [String : STCQuestion] = [ : ];

subscript(key : String?) -> STCQuestion? {
    get {
        if (key != nil) {
            return self.questionDict[key!];
        }
        return nil;
    }
    set(newValue) {
        if (key != nil) {
            self.questionDict[key!] = newValue;
        }
    }
}

func generate() -> GeneratorType {

}


 func next() -> (String, STCQuestion)? {
    if (self.questionDict.isEmpty) {
        return .None
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Do you care about the order or do you just want to use your class in for in loops like normal dictionaries? If you want a sorting you should describe what it is.

Comment: @sanz - At this point I don't care about the order, just that I could successfully iterate over all of the values inside a dictionary;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, how about just forwarding on the generate?

```
func generate() -> DictionaryGenerator<String, STCQuestion> {
    return questionDict.generate()
}
```

(You don't need to implement `GeneratorType`, just `SequenceType` should do. It's `generate()` itself that returns a `GeneratorType`, and *that*'s what has to implement `next()`, which the existing `generate()` implementation in Dictionary already does for you.)

Full worked example based on your code:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

class STCQuestion {
    let foo: String
    init(_ foo: String) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

class STCQuestionList : SequenceType {

    private var questionDict: [String : STCQuestion] = [ : ];

    subscript(key : String?) -> STCQuestion? {
        get {
            if key != nil {
                return self.questionDict[key!];
            }
            return nil;
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if key != nil {
                self.questionDict[key!] = newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    func generate() -> DictionaryGenerator<String, STCQuestion> {
        return questionDict.generate()
    }
}


var list = STCQuestionList()
list["test"] = STCQuestion("blah")
list["another"] = STCQuestion("wibble")
list["third"] = STCQuestion("doodah")

for (key, value) in list {
    println("Key: \(key) Foo: \(value.foo)")
}

// Output:
// Key: test Foo: blah
// Key: another Foo: wibble
// Key: third Foo: doodah
```

Answer (score 2):

(**Note:** I re-thought this -- original answer via the edited page...)

Swift has a generic `GeneratorOf` type that you can use to create a generator. You just provide a closure that returns the next value in the initializer:

```
class STCQuestionList : SequenceType {

    private var questionDict: [String : STCQuestion] = [ : ];

    subscript(key : String?) -> STCQuestion? {
        get {
            if (key != nil) {
                return self.questionDict[key!];
            }
            return nil;
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if (key != nil) {
                self.questionDict[key!] = newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    /// Creates a generator for each (key, value)
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<(String, STCQuestion)> {
        var index = 0
        return GeneratorOf<(String, STCQuestion)> {
            if index < self.questionDict.keys.array.count {
                let key = self.questionDict.keys.array[index++]
                return (key, self.questionDict[key]!)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order, can't you just call the same methods of dictionary or make your class a subclass of a dictionary? For example:

```
func generate() -> GeneratorType {
    return self.questionDict.generate()
}


func next() -> (String, STCQuestion)? {
    return self.questionDict.next()
}
```