# SequenceType with DictionaryGenerator - issues with Struct when Class works fine?

Tags: ios, swift, generator, sequence

Following up on a great response here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322949/5583125) regarding SequenceTypes and dictionaries.

I'm using: Xcode 7.2 and Swift 2.1

Update: To clarify, I'm running this in a Playground

This works great when the child item in the embedded dictionary is a Class, but I'm experiencing issues when using a Struct - and I'm not understanding why that is.

### Works great:

```
 class Item {
  let title: String
   init(_ title: String) {
     self.title = title
  }
}

 class ItemList : SequenceType {

  private var itemDict: [String : Item] = [ : ];

  subscript(key : String?) -> Item? {
     get {
       if key != nil {
         return self.itemDict[key!];
      }
       return nil;
    }
     set(newValue) {
       if key != nil {
         self.itemDict[key!] = newValue;
      }
    }
  }

  func generate() -> DictionaryGenerator<String, Item> {
     return itemDict.generate()
  }
}

 var list = ItemList()
 list["key1"] = Item("value1")
 list["key2"] = Item("value2")

 for (key, value) in list {
   print("Key: \(key) Foo: \(value.title)")
}
```

### Blows up:

When I change Item to be a Struct, the for-each blows up I get a "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" exception.

```
 struct Item {
  let title: String
   init(_ title: String) {
     self.title = title
  }
}

//Not so happy when Item is a struct
 for (key, value) in list {
   print("Key: \(key) Foo: \(value.title)")
}
```

Could someone clue me into why this might be?  I get the basic concepts described in Matt Gibson's response - but I don't understand why making Item a struct instead of a Class would break things.

Comment: Did you try it in a compiled project?

Comment: `class ItemList : SequenceType` should this give a compiler error because `SequenceType` has a `Self1 requirement?

Comment: @Cristik: The question (as I understand it) is about changing `class Item` to a `struct`, not `class ItemList`. But I cannot reproduce that problem (and neither can matt).

Comment: Thank you for your help, all.  Comment below - turns out this is a playground thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is something odd about the way you're testing? I tried your code in an actual iOS app and it runs fine. Here is the *complete* class ViewController class file in my test:

```
import UIKit

struct Item {
    let title: String
    init(_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class ItemList : SequenceType {

    private var itemDict: [String : Item] = [ : ];

    subscript(key : String?) -> Item? {
        get {
            if key != nil {
                return self.itemDict[key!];
            }
            return nil;
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if key != nil {
                self.itemDict[key!] = newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    func generate() -> DictionaryGenerator<String, Item> {
        return itemDict.generate()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let list = ItemList()
        list["key1"] = Item("value1")
        list["key2"] = Item("value2")

        for (key, value) in list {
            print("Key: \(key) Foo: \(value.title)")
        }


    }

}
```

Runs fine, and outputs this:

```
Key: key1 Foo: value1
Key: key2 Foo: value2
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified.  I'm trying this in a Playground.  And I agree that I feel like it should work.  But... on my box right now it's throwing exceptions.

Comment: @eww But a playground is a highly artificial world, not truly representative of how Swift works. It's _disappointing_ that this code may have problems there, but not in any way _significant_.

Comment: yeah, I have to admit I'm really surprised by that given the relative simplicity of the example.  I took the sample and put it into an actual project - worked great.  Kind of a bummer because playgrounds are a great way to just try some things out without needing to set up a dedicated project.  Lesson learned, I guess.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: great idea.  I'll do that this afternoon.

Comment: Submitted to bugreport

Comment: Thanks for doing that!